# Can't ping on CentOS when second adapter in virtualbox is enabled

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos, ping

When enabling second adapter for host-only, I cannot ping annymore it tells me unknown host but if I ping with the IP address it just works. so the problem is when I want to install a software via YUM it tells me trying different mirror. Then it just stops.

When disabling de second network adapter everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by changing ifcfg-eth1.

Added `NM_CONTROLLED=no`.

[Explanation of NM](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/what-is-the-function-of-nm_controlled-943905/)

Comment: One of the reasons you didn't get an answer is probably that you didn't actually ask a question. Did you want help troubleshooting? If so, why didn't you describe what troubleshooting you had done and what results you got? Did you want an explanation? If so, ask for one.